# I need to create a program that will read a text file, figure out in the parentheses are valid, and solve the equation

Tags: java

[This is my assignment on number 6:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/un1oc.png)

And this is what I have so far. It's not working properly and I am not sure why. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I showed what error I get at the bottom of the code. I'm not sure how to fix it and where to go from here.

```
     import java.util.Arrays;
public class st {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String aa = "8 + (2+2)";
        Init init = new Init(aa);
         }

    }

    public final class Init {

        public int top = 1;
        Integer[] stack = new Integer[10];
        String[] queue = new String[10];
        int number, x, y, z, op, front, rear;
        int finalValue;
        int CurrValue;
        String queueOperand;

        Character s;

        public Init(String s) {
            ValidateEquation(s);
            int finalVal = postFix(s);
            System.out.printf("The answer is " + finalVal + "\n");
        }

        void ValidateEquation(String s) {
            for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
                char c = s.charAt(i);
                if (c == '(') {
                    push(c);
                } else if (c == ')') {
                    if (isStackEmpty()) {
                        System.out.printf("Error: Too many ')'");
                        System.exit(0);
                    } else {
                        int closeParen = pop();
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        public int postFix(String s) {
            int CurrentCalculation;

            int i = 0;
            while (i < s.length()) {
                char c = s.charAt(i);

                if ((int) c > 47 && (int) c < 58) {
                    int numVal = Character.getNumericValue(c);
                    push(numVal);
                } else if ((int) c > 41 && (int) c < 48) {
                    String StrVal = Character.toString(c);
                    pushQ(StrVal);
                } 

                if (c == '(' || c == ')' || i == s.length()-1) {
                    String newString = "";

                    for (Integer stack1 : stack) {
                        /* iterate through the stack */
                        if (stack1 != null) {
                            newString = newString + stack1 + " ";
                        }
                    }
                    for (String queue1 : queue) {
                        /* iterate through the queue */
                        if (queue1 != null) {
                            newString = newString + queue1 + " ";
                            queueOperand = queue1;
                        }
                    }

                    if (newString.length() > 2) {
                        int CurrValue = calculateEquation(newString);

                        if ("+".equals(queueOperand)) {
                          finalValue = finalValue + CurrValue; 
                        } else if ("-".equals(queueOperand)) {
                          finalValue = finalValue - CurrValue;
                        } else if ("*".equals(queueOperand)) {
                          finalValue = finalValue * CurrValue;
                        } else if ("/".equals(queueOperand)) {
                          finalValue = finalValue / CurrValue;
                        }
                        popAll();

                     }
                }
                i++;

            }

            return finalValue;
        }

        int calculateEquation(String s) {
            for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
                char c = s.charAt(i);

                if ((int) c > 47 && (int) c < 58) {
                    int numVal = Character.getNumericValue(c);
                    push(numVal);
                }
                if ((int)c > 41 && (int)c < 48) {
                    if (s.length() <= 4) {
                        x = pop();
                        if (c == '*' || c == '/') {
                            y = 1;
                        } else {
                            y = 0;
                        }
                    } else {
                        x = pop();
                        y = pop();
                    }

                    System.out.println("\n" + x + " " + y + " " + c);

                    if (c == '+') {
                        z = x + y;
                    } else if (c == '-') {
                        z = x - y;
                    } else if (c == '*') {
                        z = x * y;
                    } else if (c == '/') {
                        z = x / y;
                    }
                }
            }
            return z;
        }

        void push(int x) {
            top = top + 1;
            /* Increment stack pointer. */
            stack[top] = x;
            /* Place x on top of stack. */
        }

        void pushQ(String x) {
            rear = rear + 1;
            /* Increment stack pointer. */
            queue[rear] = x;
            /* Place x on top of stack. */
        }

        int pop() {
            int x;
            x = stack[top];
            /* Retrieve item from top of stack. */
            top = top - 1;
            /* Decrement stack. */
            return x;
        }

        void popAll() {
            Arrays.fill(stack, null);
            Arrays.fill(queue, null);
        }

        boolean isStackEmpty() {
            boolean empty;
            empty = false;
            if (top == -1) {
                /* If top = -1, that indicates an empty stack. */
                empty = true;
            }
            return empty;
        }

    }
```

This is the error I get:

"/st.java:12: error: class Init is public, should be declared in a file named Init.java
public final class Init {"

Comment: The error seems straightforward enough - what's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You should put each public class in separate file and file name must be class name.

Comment: Is there anyway it could be all in one file?

Comment: No way I think!!